# How to hide an Ad?

Tags: android, admob, andengine

Hello I use this code below to show an Ad in my game and it works fine, but I created this banner (`setContentView()`) in `GameActivity.java`. And I have `gameScene.java`. I wanna hide this banner sometimes. So how can I reach "adView" variable (which is in GameActivity.java) from gameScene.java?

I have one activity GameActivity.java and others scenes (gameScene, menuScene...).
I want to show the banner in my menu scene,but I also want to hide it in game scene.

```java
      @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onSetContentView() {

            super.onSetContentView();
            final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
            final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.FILL);
            final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);

            adView = new AdView(this);
            adView.setAdUnitId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
            adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
            adView.refreshDrawableState();

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
                    adView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            }


            this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
            mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine, this);



            final FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            surfaceViewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

            frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
            frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);
            this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);

    }
```

Comment: You aren't giving us enough information to answer this question. What is GameScene, BaseScene? How are they created? Why can't you find adView?

Comment: GameScene is my scene where the user plays kill monsters etc BaseScene is just a class,which all of my scenesh extends there you can find some methods,which are in all of the scenesh like onBackKeyPressed() , createScene() , disposeScene() , onResume() etc.. I can't find adView,because the variable is created in another .java file GameActivity and its not visible in GameScene.java,because its in other package and I just created and instance to get the variable and exception again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it, simply call `adView.setVisiblity(View.GONE)`. If you want to show it again, call `adView.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)`.

Comment: How to reach 'adView' variable from game scene?

Comment: what is gameScene? a fragment?

Comment: no its just a class a scene for my game,GameScene.java extends BaseScene

Comment: You could define an interface in GameScene, which is implemented by your Activity. When you create the object GameScene, you pass the reference of the interface, and then when you need it you call that interface method (defined in your activity), hiding the banner

Comment: I created an instance in GameActivity and in my GameScene I use GameActivity.getInstance().adView.setVisibility(View.Gone); and it causes an error.I can't create an interface ,because gamescene must be abstract and that also causes errors

Comment: NullpointerException , scenes.GameScene.run(GameScene.java) this is the line GameActivity.getInstance().adView.setVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: Okay I tried the same thing created a method in GameActivity ,which shows a toast and try to call this method in my Game Scene not working again the same error my method for calling toast is this.runOnUIThread(new Runnable()) .. here the Toast

Answer (score 0):

Do as Alesandro suggests.

Pass a reference to the Activity into GameScene and use that reference to call findViewById to get the AdView.

Answer (score 0):

SkinWalker, I readed your posts in the AndEngine Forum and here, I had the same problem but Androidacct solved it for me. Read this post: [Hide/Show AdView from Scene](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/hide-show-adview-with-scene-t16526.html)

I hope It helps you!

**EDIT:**

This is how it help me: 
In your BaseGameActivity add this code:

```
public void showAds() {
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
                                            AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
                            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                    }
            });
    }

    public void hideAds() {
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
            });
    }
```

And you must to call it from your Scene with this code:

```
ResourcesManager.getInstance().activity.hideAds();
```

And I recommend you to read this tutorial: [Full game tutorial - part 3. Resources Manager](http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-3.html)

Best Regards!